# Getting 400 Bad Request error with AWS Application Load Balancer and Socket.IO

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, sockets, kubernetes

I have an issue with my AWS Application Load Balancer (ALB) and Socket.IO application. When trying to establish a WebSocket connection, I'm receiving a 400 Bad Request error.
Here is some relevant information about my setup:

My application is a Node.js server using Express and Socket.IO, running in a Kubernetes cluster.
My ALB has an idle timeout of 4000 seconds.
I'm using the ALB Ingress Controller in my Kubernetes cluster.

I'm using HTTPS for the connection, and the relevant ALB listener is on port 443.
My Socket.IO server is set up to handle CORS from https://mysub.mydomain.com.

```
 const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
  cors: {
   origin: 'https://mysub.mydomain.com',
   methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  credentials: true
 }
 });
```

angular:

```
this.socket = io('backend url');

this.socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('Socket connected:', this.socket.id);
});

this.socket.on('disconnect', () => {
  console.log('Socket disconnected');
});
```

Socket disconnected

POST https://backendurl/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OYb_o-8&sid=a7ojSbgO2-eFkL7zAAAd 40